# Intrapage anchor tags not working in FF / Safari

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

```
I have a nav bar structured as follows:

<template>
  <div>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href = "#contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href = "#toAbout" >About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href = "#toProperties">Properties</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href = "#toHome">Home</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div style="height: 1000px">
    </div>

    <p id="contact">
    Contact
    </p>
    <p id="toAbout">
    About
    </p>
    <p id="toProperties">
    Properties
    </p>
    <p id="toHome">
    Home
    </p>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
</script>
<style>
</style>
```

If I click the anchor in Chrome it works just fine but FF/Safari require a double click (first click changes the URL to /home#id, the second click takes them to the id.

A fiddle of the basic HTML (https://jsfiddle.net/370bvmb5/1/) is working so I'm guessing this is a Vue-Router issue?  Changing to router-link's didn't fix the issue.

Comment: Are there any JavaScript event handlers tied to the navbar elements? It looks like you're using Vue.js

Comment: Works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/k2mw5g5s/ so something's going in in the code you *haven't* shown us. An actual working example of the issue we can take a look at is important here.

Comment: Will add momentarily, thanks!

Comment: @Blazemonger yes, the container <li> has a v-if but no click events, the div containing org_nav_bar has a v-if and some :class bindings.

Comment: @ceejayoz Removed all extraneous code and still getting the error even though a fiddle with identical HTML works fine so I'm guessing it's an issue with either Vue or Vue-Router.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue was in my Vue-Router settings, I added behavior for scrolling to a hash and that fixed the issue for FF/Safari, no idea why it worked in Chrome though.

```
  scrollBehavior: function (to, from, savedPosition) {
    if (to.hash) {
      return {selector: to.hash}
    } else {
      return { x: 0, y: 0 }
    }
  },
```

Comment: Note that in Vue Router 4 you need to change `selector` to `el`, `x` to `left` and `y` to `top` for this to work.